# modeling associations in Rails for Course, Institute, Location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, data-modeling, table-relationships

### **I was working on an App which has the following requirement:**

An admin (active_admin) can create courses for institutes.

The relations between the entities are as follows:

> Course belongs to Institute 
>   ( each course can belong to only one Institute).

---

> An `Institute` can have many `Locations` where it offers various `Courses`.

Each `Location` for an `Institute` can provide many `Courses` and Each `Course` can be taught in many `Locations`

Im an not able to create a relation between Entities in such a way, so that the creation of a new `Course` requires the creation of `Institutes` and its `Locations`. Without `Institutes` and `Location` present `Course` cannot be created.

### The way I was trying to achieve this was

`Course` can be taught in many `Locations` through `Institutes`.

But wasn't able to relate the Entities, such that the creation of `Course` required the creation of `Institutes` and its Locations.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

First, add `institute_id` (integer) column to Course table if you haven't. In order to that run `rails g migration AddInstituteIDColumnToCourse institute_id:integer` this will create a file in db/migrate you can check there.Then run `rake db:migrate` to commit this change to database. And in your `Institute` model paste `has_many :courses` after that in your `Course` model paste `belongs_to :institute` with these steps the relation between `Institute` and `Course` has been created. You can create same relations with these steps between `Location` and `Institute` you just need to change some necessary part of these codes.

You need to use `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation between `Course` and `Location`
in order to do that first you need to create a migration file like this `rails g migration CreateJoinTableCourseLocation course_id:integer location_id:integer` and run `rake db:migrate` this will create a table that stores each `Course` taught in many `Location` and the opposite way.Check this in db/migrate folder. Then in your `Location` model paste `has_and_belongs_to_many :courses` and same for `Course` model `has_and_belongs_to_many :locations`. You can query each course given on a location with: `location.courses`, and the opposite gives you locations that a course is taught  `course.locations`. Hope it helps